# Crear un diccionario con una List genérica como parámetro

Tags: vb.net, lista

Buen dia.

Quiero crear un diccionario de datos y pasar una lista como un parametro de esta.

Por ejemplo tengo el siguiente diccionario para pasar un DataTable

```
Private Shared _tablasMaestras As New Dictionary(Of String, System.Data.DataTable)
```

Sin embargo cuando quiero hacer lo mismo con una lista generica no me reconoce el T.

```
Private Shared _ListasMaestras As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of T))
```

Provicionalmente hice lo siguiente:

```
Private Shared _ListaGastoResumenMaestras As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of ESCG_Gasto_Resumen))
```

Donde ESCG_Gasto_Resumen es un objeto que para un caso en particular me funciona bien pero tengo varias listas y no es optimo crear un diccionario por cada una de ellas pudiendo crear una sola con una lista generica que me acepte cualquier objeto como parametro (T).

Espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Hola Luis. Bienvenido. El idioma de este sitio es el español, deberías traducir tu pregunta o hacerla en el sitio en inglés. Por otra parte deberías aclarar mejor tu pregunta para que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: @Luis Espinoza una consulta te da algun error

Comment: Me sale que T no esta definido

Comment: No puedes usar genéricos de esta manera. Podrías usar el tipo `Dynamic`, o el Interfaz IList. No parece tener mucho sentido de todas maneras mezclar tipos que no tienen nada que ver dentro de la misma colección, tal vez debas replantearte una refactorización de tu código.